# YUI3 Datatable - Drag and Drop columns, function getTbodyEl does not exist

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

I'm wondering how can I make the order of the columns sortable in a YUI 3 Datatable.

Following an example where rows are sortable I found that I have to create an instance of `Y.DD` to each row. Trying to do the same with columns, but the function `getTbodyEl()` does not exist.

Has anyone accomplished this? Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Y.DD` is [Drag and Drop](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/dd/). This would help only if you want to **drag** the columns to sort them.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/ahfHx/) is one way of programmatically sorting the columns.

I haven't read the documentation for [Y.DataTable](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.html), but you can sort the `columns` attribute, subscribe to the `columnsChange` event and then make the datatable re-render*.